# write in form of $x+iy$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Can somebody help me, can somebody give a hint to solve this question

$\dfrac{\log z}{z^{3}-(1+i)(z)} $  at  $z=1+i$

actually, I want to but it in the form of $x+iy.$

Comment: Then replace all the $z$'s for $x+iy$'s...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to evaluate $\log(z) \; $ and simplify the term.
$$i+1=\sqrt2*e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi ik}$$
$$\log(i+1)=\frac12*\ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{4}i+2\pi ik \;\text{ for every integer $k$ because the polar form is }2\pi i\; \text{periodic.}$$

Comment: You probably meant $\frac\pi4i$

Comment: Ups, typo gonna edit

Comment: thanks dear. just it is ln(root of 2).. thank you